# delete duplicate strings in csv using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file like this:

```
num1;num2;num3;num4;num5
1;2;3;4;5
5;6;7;8;9
1;2;;4;5
2;3;4;5;6
```

Num1 is the main paramemer, I can see it has a duplicate strings (first and third strings). I would like to delete duplicate string 3 (1;2;;4;5) because it has $null in num3 column. How do I do this using powershell?

Comment: So you want to delete any duplicate Num1 value that has an empty Num3?

Comment: Yes.... Are you removing the line because of the duplicate or the null value or both?

Comment: Yes, I'm removing the line because its already present AND has nothing in num3.

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-CSV "C:\temp\test.csv" -Delimiter ";" | 
    Where-Object{$_.Num3} | 
    Sort-Object -Unique Num1 | 
    Export-Csv "C:\temp\test1.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

This will take the file and import it as a custom object. Then, remove any entry where `Num3` is empty/ not populated. After we use `Sort-Object` to remove and duplicates of `Num1`

There are **caveats** doing it this way; Don't know how to determine which entry is the duplicate and sorting might impact the output. Also this would quote the output, which should not be a bad thing.

Also this code is redundant with your data set since the `Where` and `Sort` would remove the same line. If you data contains lines with only one of the criteria ( dup or null ) then this code would filter them.

## Different approach

Ok, so the code above is, not surprisingly, removing extra data that you did not expect. Most likely since the conditions are evaluated separately like an OR as supposed to AND which is what you are looking for. I changed your test data to account for these variances to prove the resolve.

This solution rebuilds the data set check for duplicates as it goes. If a duplicate for `Num1` is found we check if the `Num3` for that record to see if it is null or empty.

**Test Data** in csv file

```
num1 num2 num3 num4 num5
---- ---- ---- ---- ----
1    2    3    4    5   
5    6         8    9   
1    2         4    5   
1    2    7    4    5   
2    3    4    5    6
```

So we can see where `Num1` = 5 that `Num3` is null and there is a `Num1` = 1 and `Num3` = 7. These should not be filtered out since they do not satisfy both requirements.

```powershell
$scrubbed = @()
$data = import-csv C:\temp\test.csv -Delimiter ";"

$data | ForEach-Object{
    If($scrubbed.Num1 -contains $_.Num1){
        # We already have this Num1 check to see if it is null
        If($_.Num3){
            # Num3 is populated so it can be added. 
            $scrubbed += $_
        }
    } Else {
        # This Num1 is unique and should be added. 
        $scrubbed += $_
    }
}

# Output to file
$scrubbed | Export-Csv "C:\temp\test1.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Should net the output as shown below that is written back as a semicolon delimited file.

```
num1 num2 num3 num4 num5
---- ---- ---- ---- ----
1    2    3    4    5   
5    6         8    9   
1    2    7    4    5   
2    3    4    5    6
```

Comment: Does sort-object seek for unique Num1 everywhere, i.e. in Num2, Num3, Num4? It has to be only for Num1. The code removes a lot of correct strings now

Comment: This code would remove lines where num1 exists already in the num1 column. _or_ if num3 is blank

Comment: How to make if follow this behavior: 1) Found that Num1 already exists, If so, check for empty Num3 field and remove it?

Comment: OK, the question is how to find a duplicate(s) in the first column of the csv? Another part would be an easy work to be done via foreach.

Comment: @mzv see my update. If that is not what you want please update your sample to make it more complex. So that we can see other examples of what should and should not be filtered out.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working. Foreach-object waits for interactive input. "process[0]:"

Comment: I just double checked and the code works. Make sure you copy and paste the whole content. What PowerShell version do you have? Not that it should matter. @mzv

Comment: Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1

Comment: Did you update the paths to suit your environment? if `$data` was null I could see this maybe happen

Comment: No, everything seems ok.