# Powershell - Deleting specific duplicates/triplicates in a CSV based on multiple field criteria

Tags: csv, powershell, duplicates

I have a job that collects OS info from multiple servers. Several CSV files are generated that contain Servername, OSCaption, OSversion(simplified for this example). If the server is reachable, the OSCaption and OSVersion fields get filled correctly. If not, an error message gets stuffed in the OSCaption field of the output file, the other field (OSVersion)stays empty. The job is run multiple times under different credentials to collect as much OS info as possible. In the end I combine the CSV's and I need a method to delete a certain type of duplicate/triplicate, etc.. I want to keep a single instance of a servername with a good OS field, deleting any records of the same servername with errors but I also want to keep any single instance of the error message in OSCaption if the server was not reachable at all.

I have an unsorted CSV input file that looks like this:

```
Servername,OSCaption,OSVersion
Server1,Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise ,6.1.7601
Server2,Access denied,
Server2,Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise ,6.1.7601
Server3,RDP Error,
Server4,Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise ,6.1.7601
Server2,Access Denied,
Server5 Access Denied,
```

You can see that Server2 was run under three credetials and the 2nd one worked. I want to throw out the two error records for Server2. I need the output CSV to look like this:

```
Servername,OSCaption,OSVersion
Server1,Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise ,6.1.7601
Server2,Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise ,6.1.7601
Server3,RDP Error,
Server4,Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise ,6.1.7601
Server5 Access Denied,
```

I still want the error records for Server3 and Server5 though, in the absence of any good usable OSCaption, OSversion entries.

Here is some code I was playing with from another post

```
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170660/delete-duplicate-strings-in-csv-using-powershell


$scrubbed = @()
$data = import-csv C:\posh\duptest.csv #| sort Servername,OSversion 

$data | ForEach-Object{
    If($scrubbed.servername -contains $_.servername){
    # We already have this Num1 check to see if it is null
    If($_.osversion){
        # Num3 is populated so it can be added. 
        $scrubbed += $_
        }
    } Else {
        # This Num1 is unique and should be added. 
        $scrubbed += $_
    }
}

# Output to file
$scrubbed | Export-Csv "C:\posh\scrubbed.csv" -NoTypeInformation

ii "C:\posh\scrubbed.csv"
```

It seems not to be able to handle three servernames that are the same, leaving me with two server2 records. Aside from re-running several times on subsequent output files, is there a more elegant way to do this? get-unique does not seem to do what I thought it did.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have CSV files like below:

**test1.csv:**

```
Computer Name,Msg 1,Msg 2
COMPUTER 1,Windows 8,Another msg
COMPUTER 2,Windows XP,Yet again another msg
COMPUTER 3,Access Denied,
COMPUTER 4,Windows 7,Message
COMPUTER 5,Access Denied,
```

**test2.csv:**

```
Computer Name,Msg 1,Msg 2
COMPUTER 1,Access Denied,
COMPUTER 2,Access Denied,
COMPUTER 3,Windows XP,Yet again another msg
COMPUTER 4,Windows 7,Message
COMPUTER 5,Access Denied,
```

First of all you need to import all the files you wish to process:

```
$a = Import-Csv .\test1.csv
$b = Import-Csv .\test2.csv
```

Following this we combine all the input into one big array to process:

```
$c = $a + $b
```

We first to need to group the rows on the "Computer Name" column. To do this we use the `Group-Object` cmdlet using "Computer Name" as the property name to group on.

This will give us an array with two properties. The first property being the "Computer Name" field. The second field being an array of rows from the original array which have that particular "Computer Name".

This means we can select from this "inner array" the most appropriate row. The most appropriate row is the first row which has a non-empty 3rd column or failing that the first row.

```
$d = $c | Group-Object -Property "Computer Name" | % {
    $goodRow = $_.Group | ? { [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.'msg 2') -ne $true } | Select -First 1
    if ($goodRow -eq $null) {
        $_.Group | Select -First 1
    } else {
        $goodRow
    }
}
```

We now have what we want in variable `$d` and we use `Export-Csv` to save it to a new file.

```
$d | Export-Csv .\test3.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your Specific CSV Example, and assuming that OSVersion Column filled only when there is no errors, you can try this approach:

```
$Array = @()
$csv = Import-Csv C:\temp.csv
$group = $csv | group servername
foreach ($item in $group)
{
    if ($item.Count -eq 1)
    {
    $Array += $item.Group
    }

        else
        {
        $array += $item.Group | ? {$_.OSVersion}
        }
}
```

`$Array` Results:

```
Servername OSCaption                                    OSVersion
---------- ---------                                    ---------
Server1    Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise  6.1.7601 
Server2    Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise  6.1.7601 
Server3    RDP Error                                             
Server4    Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise  6.1.7601 
Server5    Access Denied
```

**BUT:**
In Case that you will have a server (for example Server6) with errors only you will not see the results of that server at all, to solve this replace the `else` Section with this:

```
 else
    {
        if ($item.Group.OSVersion -match '\d')
        {
        $array += $item.Group | ? {$_.OSVersion}
        }
            else
            {
            $Row = "" | Select Servername,OSCaption,OSVersion
            $Row.Servername = $item.Group[0].Servername
            $Row.OSCaption = $item.Group.OSCaption -join ','
            $array += $Row
            }
    }
```

The results will be:

```
Servername OSCaption                                    OSVersion
---------- ---------                                    ---------
Server1    Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise  6.1.7601 
Server2    Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise  6.1.7601 
Server3    RDP Error                                             
Server4    Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise  6.1.7601 
Server5    Access Denied                                         
Server6    RDP Error,Access Denied,RDP Error
```

Answer (score 0):

the solutions posted look good. just wanted to provide a another alternative:

this is assuming that for those servers where you get an error the osversion column value will be blank.

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\serverinfo.csv |
  Group-Object Servername | 
    ForEach-Object {if($_.count -gt 1) {$_.group | Where-Object osversion}else{$_.group} }
```